# Counting occurrences of each number

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with a bunch of 3 digit numbers like this:

```
 0  2  3
 0  2  3
 0  2  9
 0  3  9
 0  9  2
 0  9  2
 0  9  9
 1  2  2
 1  2  2
 1  2  2
 1  2  9
 1  2  9
 1  3  3
 1  9  2
 1  9  2
 1  9  2
 1  9  3
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 1  9  9
 2  0  2
 2  0  3
```

I would like to count the number of each number that is duplicated and how many times.  Like this:

```
 0  2  3     2
 0  9  2     2
 1  2  2     3
 etc
```

So far The following came close to solving the problem; but it bypasses some numbers:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::set src=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers.txt
::set dst=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers_Converted.txt

set src=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers.txt
set dst=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers_Converted.txt
set /a row=1
set /a count=0
set line=
(for /F "delims=" %%L in ('sort %src%') do (
   if ~!line!~ == ~%%L~ (set /a row+=1 
   set /a count=row )
   if not ~!line!~ == ~%%L~ (echo !count!    %%L
   set line=%%L
   set /a row=1)
)) > "%dst%"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: OP does include code they're already trying, and describes how it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces between the digits and use that number as an array index you increment

```
::Q:\Test\2019\02\13\SU_1405402.cmd
@Echo off
set "src=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers.txt"
set "dst=F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers_Converted.txt"
:: clear array 
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in ('set arr[ 2^>Nul') do @set "%%A="
:: fill array
for /f "tokens=1-3" %%A in (%src%) do set /a "Arr[%%A%%B%%C]+=1"
:: output array
(for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%A in ('set Arr[ 2^>Nul') Do if %%B gtr 1 Echo:%%A %%B
)>%dst%
```

The batch will yield this output:

```
> type F:\DB\batchFiles\Numbers_Converted.txt
023 2
092 2
122 3
129 2
192 3
199 4
```

BTW in PowerShell this is a one liner:

```
> Get-Content .\numbers.txt| Group-Object -NoElement| Where-Object count -gt 1

Count Name
----- ----
    2  0  2  3
    2  0  9  2
    3  1  2  2
    2  1  2  9
    3  1  9  2
    4  1  9  9
```

Comment: Used LotPings' power shell solution and works perfectly.    thanks

Comment: Thanks for feedback, if you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](ttps://superuser.com/help/why-vote)